# How to make file_get_contents return the current session?

Tags: php, session

I have an endpoint on one of my websites that returns the currently logged in user from the session like this.

http://www.example.com/?whoIsLoggedIn

```
echo json_encode([
    'user_id' => $_SESSION['user_id']
]);
```

When I hit that url from my browser, I get the id of the currently logged in user like this:

```
{"user_id":23}
```

I have another website on a different domain and different server that I would like to retrieve the session from the first website. But it does not seem to be session aware.

http://www.example2.com/

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/?whoIsLoggedIn');
echo $homepage;
```

But what I get back every time is this

```
{"user_id":null}
```

Is there a way to do this somehow?

Comment: You need to call that URL from the client (you could make it in JS). If you use `file_get_contents()`, then it's the server that makes the request, not the client (which is the one that's logged in and have the correct session cookies).

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes I need to make the request from the client. I thought PHP could do that.

Comment: But how could I do it from the client and then log in with PHP?

Comment: How would the second server know? After all there can be multiple sessions at the same time. The browser gets a cookie related to the session and passes that back on each request, so your server knows which session it is. The other website doesn't have this cookie, so when it makes a request, it's as if a new client connects.

Comment: What you're asking about is called SSO (single sign on). That's a too broad of a subject to be properly explained here. You should do some research about it. There are also libraries to make it easier to set up SSO servers and clients, but you should familiarize yourself with the subject first.

Comment: Most likely there is no session yet.